# How to parse a number as base 10?

Tags: javascript

In [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748801/what-happens-when-a-number-has-a-leading-zero), I discovered that a number with a leading 0 is parsed as an octal number. In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/how-do-i-work-around-javascripts-parseint-octal-behavior/850346), [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/850346/1101095) says:

> This is a common Javascript gotcha with a simple solution:
>
> Just specify the base, or 'radix', like so:
>
> parseInt('08',10); // 8

That works, but only if the number is enclosed in quotes. Consider the following example:

```
var test = 0132;
alert(parseInt(test, 10));
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VU96M/2/

The output of that is "90," not "132."

So, as you can see, the solution does not work int this case.

If I have a variables passed to a function as a parameter, or returned from a function, that has a leading zero like the above variable `test`, how can I parse it as a base 10 value?

Comment: Well, for one: `parseInt(test), 10); != parseInt(test, 10);`

Comment: `0132` is parsed as an octal number as soon as it's encountered, before `parseInt` is even called...

Comment: @mikeTheLiar - A type on my part, I updated the question.

Comment: @DCoder - So, if the value is returned from a function, or is passed as an argument, how do I get it in base 10?

Comment: Your code shows a numeric literal but you are talking about a variable passed as a parameter or returned from a function. Can you show that code? It is surely easy to avoid in a literal by just not prepending with leading zeroes.

Comment: If you're returning numbers from a function with a leading 0, then you are returning octal numbers. If that's not what you want, then change your function.

Comment: A number is a number is a number. `0132` (octal) is the same number as `90` (decimal) is the same as `0x5A` (hex). A *string representation of the number* differs according to the base, the value of the number itself doesn't. Don't create number literals with leading zeroes, convert all strings to numbers using `parseInt(v, 10)`, and be done with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0132 is treated as an octal before it is passed to `parseInt`,  so you are really calling `parseInt(90,10)`

Try this instead:

```
var test = 0132;
parseInt((test).toString(8)); // 132
```

Answer (score 2):

In [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) JavaScript doesn't allow you to do such things – define an octal literal – and you will get an exception instead. It's really a good practice start to use the strict mode as default mode for your JavaScript code.

Also because in non strict mode you don't have a clue if `test` variable was defined as octal literal or decimal, so `test.toString(8)` will give you of course different results if `test` was defined as `0132` or `132`.

Answer (score 1):

You can change it back to a base 8 literal so it will return the base 10 version:

```
console.log( +test.toString(8) ); // 132
//                 ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[***Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/9pBQw/)